# What's the best way to make a Flask route "fall through" to another Flask route?

Tags: python, flask

I have two Flask routes.

```
@app.route("/")
def root():
    return render_template("/login.html")

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("/login.html")
```

Instead of the above code, I'd like to just have `root()` automatically return whatever `login()` returns, so if I change something in `login()`, I don't have to make the same change in `root()`. The obvious way is

```
def root():
    return login()
```

But this doesn't seem right, since `login` isn't actually `login`, it's `login` wrapped with the `app.route` decorator. Will this cause problems?

Another way would be to use `redirect`, but I don't want to make the user make an unnecessary extra HTTP request for something I could handle in the backend.

Another way would be to just assign the `login` function to both the `/` and `/login` routes, but let's assume I want to have a separate `root()` function for some reason, maybe just because it makes it easier to change the `/` route later on, or because I want to do some initial setup before rendering the login page.

What's the most idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: `@app.route("/", "/login")` this will work for both url

Comment: @Avi That's a good short-term solution, but this is the kind of thing I said I'm trying to avoid in the last paragraph of the question. EDIT: Also, I get a "too many arguments" error - which version of Flask is that for?

Comment: I'm sorry the exact answer for my above comment is like this `@app.route("/") //press enter @app.route("/login") press enter def yourfunction`

Answer (score 1):

To create a "fallback" route, i.e. route that would be invoked when no other more specific route matches.

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def root(path):
    return render_template("/login.html")
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. I don't want every path ever to go to the login page, just one. Also, this again seems like the kind of thing I tried to exclude in the last paragraph of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Create an if statement in your root function that checks if user is logged in and if not then redirect to login route?

Other than that, I think that all options are already mentioned.